# How do symmetric powers of direct products decompose?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, tensor-products, symmetric-groups

Let $G_i$ be groups (in my case, compact simple and Lie), and $R_i$ finite-dimensional representations thereof. Also, $S^n$ and $\wedge^n$ denote symmetrized/anti-symmetrized tensor powers of a given representation.

We consider a representation of $G_1\times G_2\times\cdots$ of the form $(R_1,R_2,\dots)$. I am trying to reduce tensor powers of the form
$$
S^n(R_1,R_2,\dots),\qquad \wedge^n(R_1,R_2,\dots)
$$
into powers in the individual components. For example it is clear that
$$
\begin{aligned}
S^2(R_1,R_2)&=(S^2R_1,S^2R_2)\oplus (\wedge^2R_1,\wedge^2R_2)\\
\wedge^2(R_1,R_2)&=(S^2R_1,\wedge^2R_2)\oplus (\wedge^2R_1,S^2R_2)
\end{aligned}
$$
Higher powers are trickier to me. For example I expect something like
$$
S^n(R_1,R_2)\overset?=\sum_{\lambda,\lambda'}(S^\lambda R_1,S^{\lambda'}R_2)
$$
where $\lambda,\lambda'$ are suitable partitions of $n$ and $S^\lambda$ is the corresponding symmetrizer.

How can these products be reduced in general? Where can I find an (elementary, if possible) introduction to this problem? In particular, I would like to see how $S^3(R_1,R_2)$ and $\wedge^3(R_1,R_2)$ decompose. I might be able to guess the general structure given these two cases.

Comment: Indeed, Cauchy's formula gives $S^n(E\otimes F)=\bigoplus_{\lvert\lambda\rvert=n}S^\lambda E\otimes S^\lambda F$ and $\Lambda^n(E\otimes F)=\bigoplus_{\lvert\lambda\rvert=n}S^\lambda E\otimes S^{\lambda'}F$ (where $\lambda'$ is the transpose of $\lambda$) when working over characteristic 0 fields.  If you want a characteristic-free treatment, see [Akin, Buchsbaum & Weyman (1982)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870882900391), or chapter 2 (maybe also chapter 3) of Weyman's *Cohomology of vector bundles and syzygies*.

Comment: @user10354138 Great, thanks! Char-0 is fine for me. Does Cauchy's formula have a more specific name? There are many formulas after him and google is not helping to find the right one. By the way, does the formula includes multiplicity so e.g. $(2,1)$ appears twice? Thanks in advance, D.